# HBase ZooKeeper

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am newbie to HBase and trying to configure HBase on Ubuntu 14.04. After configuration and starting HBase (to get to HBase CLI). If I run any HBase command, I get the node `/hbase` is not in ZooKeeper. 
Please find below my `hbase-site.xml` and `zoo.cfg`.

```
  <configuration>
     <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost/hbase</value>
   <description>Enter the HBase NameNode server hostname</description>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
       <value>true</value>
    </property>

   <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  <description> The port at which the clients will connect.
  </description>
   </property>

   <property> 
     <name>hbase.master.port</name>
     <value>2080</value>
    <description>The port the HBase Master should bind to.</description>
   </property>

   <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>

    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/var/lib/zookeeper</value>
      <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The directory where the snapshot is stored.
       </description>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
    </property>

 </configuration>
```

Zoo.cfg

```
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
```

Appreciate all your help/support in advance.

Comment: Please do not type your tile in ALL CAPS. It is considered SHOUTING here (as it is on most web sites), it won't get you answers any sooner, and it's very rude and annoying. It's also harder to read. If you look at the main page, you won't find any other questions typed in ALL CAPS. Please stop doing so as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you set hbase.zookeeper.quorum in hbase-site.xml, like this:

```
 <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
     <value>your_zookeeper_url:2181</value> 
 </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `zookeeper.znode.parent` property value to `/hbase-unsecure` and let me know

```
<property>
  <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
  <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add classpath for hbase/lib in hadoop-env.sh in my case. Adding hbase classpath resolved my issue. 
Regards
Anil Khiani

Answer (score 0):

Here is my hbase-site.xml, i hope it helps :

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
 <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hbase.master</name>
      <value>localhost:60000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  
  <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
         <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```